# python - Assigning a string to a field object

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm working on Google BigQuery's python client.
I'm writing a program to automate the creation/exporting of tables.

Everything is working fine but there is a slight problem - I'd like to take in the schema of the table as an input from the user.

Here's how the table schema is assigned currently:

```
 table.schema = (
    bigquery.SchemaField('Name', 'STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Gender', 'STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Frequency', 'INTEGER')
)
```

It's hardcoded in the code.

I've written the code to process the user input and convert it to the format mentioned above.

What my code returns is a string - `bq_schema` - which looks like:

```
bigquery.SchemaField(Name, STRING),bigquery.SchemaField(Gender, STRING),bigquery.SchemaField(Frequency, INTEGER)
```

Now when I try to assign this string to the table schema,

```
table.schema = (bq_schema)
```

I get an error stating `Schema items must be fields`

So how do I make the table schema dynamic depending on the user input?

EDIT: As requested, here the code for converting user input to string:

```
s_raw = raw_input('\n\nEnter the schema for the table in the following format- fieldName:TYPE, anotherField:TYPE\n')
s = s_raw.split(',')
schema = []

for obj in s:
    temp = obj.split(':')
    schema.append(temp[0])
    schema.append(temp[1])

bq_schema = ''

for i in range(0, len(schema), 2):
    bq_schema+=('bigquery.SchemaField(\'{}\', \'{}\'),'.format(schema[i], schema[i+1]))
```

Comment: The return of your code cannot be a string indeed. As the schema `setter property`is defined: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py#L106 you can see that it evaluates if all fields are instance of `SchemaField` so you have no option other then returning `SchemaField` values. Do you have an example of what is the user input in your system? Do you mind showing us how you are converting this input to the string you mentioned before?

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I've added the code in the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: What my code returns is a string - bq_schema

What you are facing ist the `__str__` Represantation of the `bigquery` object.

Change the following:

```
bq_schema = []
for i in range(0, len(schema), 2):
    bq_schema.append(SchemaField(schema[i], schema[i+1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

To define how a field behaves in BigQuery you basically need [3 inputs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/schema.py#L18): `name`, `type` and the `mode`.

One issue you might find when processing the input schema is managing fields of type `RECORD` because each of those fields have defined inside of them other fields.

This being the case, it would be somewhat difficult for a user to give you in strings what schema setup he's working with.

What I recommend you to do therefore is to receive a JSON like input data with the correspondent schema. For instance, you could receive this as input:

```
[{"name": "sku", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "type", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"fields":
     [{"name": "id", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}, {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}],
    "name": "category", "type": "RECORD", "mode": "REPEATED"},
   {"name": "description", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"name": "manufacturer", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]
```

Notice that this JSON fully defines a schema in a straightforward manner. The field "category" is of type "RECORD" and it contains the schema definitions for each of its child fields, that is, "name" and "id".

In Python, all you'd have to do is processing this JSON input them. This function might do the trick:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField
def get_schema_from_json(input_json, res=[]):
     if not input_json:
         return res
     cur = input_json.pop()
     res.append(SchemaField(name=cur['name'], field_type=cur['type'], mode=cur['mode'], fields = None if 'fields' not in cur else get_schema_from_json(cur['fields'], [])))
     return get_schema_from_json(input_json, res)
```

And then you just can extract the schema like so:

```
table.schema = get_schema_from_json(user_json_input_data)
```